# Printf formatting error incompatible types

Tags: java, printf, bluej, incompatibletypeerror

I keep getting this error saying incompatible types: `java.io.PrintStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String` and I don't get how to get it to work for my toString Method. I've tried assigning it to a variable and then returning it, and then just plan printing it out as a return statement, I don't see anything wrong with my printf formatting. Help is appreciated.

```
 import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class Item
    {
        private String name;
        private double price;
        private int quantity;


        // -------------------------------------------------------
        //  Create a new item with the given attributes.
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        public Item (String itemName, double itemPrice, int numPurchased)
        {
        name = itemName;
        price = itemPrice;
        quantity = numPurchased;
        }


        // -------------------------------------------------------
        //   Return a string with the information about the item
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        public String toString ()
        {

        return System.out.printf("%-15s $%-8.2f %-11d $%-8.2f", name, price, 
     quantity, price*quantity);
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------
        //   Returns the unit price of the item
        // -------------------------------------------------
        public double getPrice()
        {
        return price;
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------
        //   Returns the name of the item
        // -------------------------------------------------
        public String getName()
        {
        return name;
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------
        //   Returns the quantity of the item
        // -------------------------------------------------
        public int getQuantity()
        {
        return quantity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to print a double as a float, use `d` for doubles, `f` for floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return System.out.printf("%-15s $%-8.2f %-11d $%-8.2f", name, price, 
     quantity, price*quantity);
```

You are trying to return `PrintStream`. That is not correct caause the toString should return a String.

You should have used [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method, which gives back a String after fomratting

```
return String.format("%-15s $%-8.2f %-11d $%-8.2f", name, price, 
         quantity, price*quantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.printf` does not return a string, You are looking for `String.format`

```
public String toString () {
    return String.format("%-15s $%-8.2f %-11d $%-8.2f", name, price, quantity, price*quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 System.out.printf("%-15s $%-8.2f %-11d $%-8.2f", name, price, 
 quantity, price*quantity);
```

to

```
 String.format("%-15s $%-8.2f %-11d $%-8.2f", name, price, 
 quantity, price*quantity);
```

Because `System.out.println()` if for printing a string to console. Not to create a formated string-

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by

```
return System.out.printf(....)
```

If you really want to return a String from this method then try

```
return String.format(....);
```

Comment: @dawood-ibn-kareem Thanks for the edit.  Did you get married and change your name?

Comment: Not recently.  Just my handle here.